# mysql left join but return blank row

Tags: mysql, return, join

i have a small problem where i have this setup...

Table: trade names {     trade_id  : 1     trade_name : olivers guest house}

Table Customer    { name: me, trade_id: 1 : blah: blah}

i do a left join to get the trade name into customers as if you are a guest house you will have a trade name but as a landlord you will not have a trade name, but i still want a result to come back.

so all is good.... nope.  i display the results in a table which has a search by postcode AND trade.

i do a select where postcode like %postcode% AND trade like %trade% which will bring back the criteria that match.

As the left join wont bring back a trade for the landlord anything with out a trade is excluded from the results.

I was wondering if there was some way to say if the row does not exist return a blank field.

so it would be like this:

```
array([0] => array([0] =>[name] = "something" ["trade_name"] = "olivers guest house" [type] = "guest house").
             array[0] => [name] = "something" ["trade_name"] = " " [type] = "landlord");
```

as currently i get

```
array([0] => array([0] =>[name] = "something" ["trade_name"] = "olivers guest house" [type] = "guest house").
             array[0] => [name] = "something" ["trade_name"] = "NULL" [type] = "landlord");
```

which the where trade_name like %trade% cant work on.

I hope i havent over complicated the description.

i hope there is just some type of join that would do it but i cant see one :(

Thankys guys

Comment: Could you *at least* provide the SELECT query that you're using, please?

Answer (score 0):

In your query (which I think you haven't posted) you should replace:

```
SELECT trade_name, ....
```

with:

```
SELECT COALESCE(trade_name, ' '), ....
```

or alternatively you can use the MySQL specific funciton [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull):

```
SELECT IFNULL(trade_name, ' '), ....
```

Comment: Thank you, i shall try that now and get back to you :)

Comment: It does what i want it to do as a result set but doesnt work with the like:

Comment: It does what i want it to do as a result set but doesnt work with the SQL as i say : IFNULL(details_business_trading_details.trading_name,"7") AS trading_name,  then i say  WHERE common_details_address.postcode LIKE '%%' AND details_business_trading_details.trading_name LIKE '%%' but im guessing that doesnt work due to how it works

Comment: @stephen cooper: Remember that `details_business_trading_details.trading_name` can be NULL which will cause your WHERE clause to fail. You need to use COALESCE or IFNULL there too.